# Conditional query construction in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Server Query which performs a simple inner join:

```
SELECT  
    SUM(Amount) as Total
FROM dbo.InvestmentTransactions IT
INNER JOIN dbo.InvestmentEntities IE ON IE.InvestmentEntityId = IT.InvestmentEntityId AND IT.InvestmentEntityId IN (@Id_List)
```

The Join condition is based on a list of IDs I will supply as a list of Ids via a parameter (the above resides in a stored procedure).

My goal is to check if the parameter is empty in which case it should join on all.  Something like the following:

```
SELECT  
    SUM(Amount) as Total
FROM dbo.InvestmentTransactions IT
INNER JOIN dbo.InvestmentEntities IE ON IE.InvestmentEntityId = IT.InvestmentEntityId **IF !EMPTY @Id_list THEN : AND IT.InvestmentEntityId IN (@Id_List) END IF**
```

Is the above possible in a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Comment: `IT.InvestmentEntityId IN (@Id_List)` is not valid syntax. If you are passing a comma-separated list, you'll need to use `CROSS APPLY` and `STRING_SPLIT`.

Comment: Instead of passing in a delimited list of values you should look at instead passing in a table valued parameter.

Comment: @DanGuzman Could you show me hbow to use Cross Apply in this situation to accomplish the same as String_split  and are there any benefits to using one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming @Id_List contains comma separated values.

```
SELECT  
SUM(Amount) as Total
FROM dbo.InvestmentTransactions IT
INNER JOIN dbo.InvestmentEntities IE ON IE.InvestmentEntityId = IT.InvestmentEntityId 
AND (IT.InvestmentEntityId IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Id_List, ',')) OR @Id_List is Null)
```